# SQL NOT IN clause isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Does anyone see where the issue is with this SQL code?  I keep getting red underscores around the FROM lines in the query with the UNION.  If you're able to also tell me how I can prevent the duplication of code, even better!!

```
DECLARE @collection_site_address_id INT;
SET @collection_site_address_id = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        client_address.addressid 
    FROM 
        dbo.ws_test_request
        INNER JOIN client ON ws_test_request.collection_site_id = client.identifyingnumber
        INNER JOIN client_address ON client.clientid = client_address.clientid
    WHERE 
        sample_specimen_id = @sample_identifyingnumber
        AND client_address.addresstypeid = 1
)

IF (

    (SELECT TOP 1
        client_address.addressid 
    FROM 
        dbo.ws_test_request
        INNER JOIN client ON ws_test_request.collection_site_id = client.identifyingnumber
        INNER JOIN client_address ON client.clientid = client_address.clientid
    WHERE 
        sample_specimen_id = @sample_identifyingnumber
        AND client_address.addresstypeid = 1
    )

    NOT IN (

        SELECT 
            [address].addressid
        FROM  
            [address]
            JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    client_address.addressid, 
                    client_address.addresstypeid, 
                FROM 
                    dbo.fnClientRelatives(@clientid, 0, 1, 0) relatives
                    INNER JOIN client_address on client_address.clientid = relatives.clientid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN client ON relatives.clientid = dbo.client.clientid

                UNION

                SELECT 
                    contact_address.addressid, 
                    contact_address.addresstypeid, 
                FROM 
                    clientcontact 
                    INNER JOIN contact_address ON contact_address.contactid=clientcontact.contactid and clientcontact.clientid=@clientid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [contact] ON [clientcontact].contactid = [contact].contactid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [address] ON contact_address.addressid = address.addressid
            ) AS client_addressexternal ON client_addressexternal.addressid = address.addressid 
        WHERE  
            client_addressexternal.addresstypeid IN (3,1) 
    )
)
BEGIN
    @collection_site_address_id = @default_collection_site_address_id
END
```

========

## Answer:

After a bit of investigation, it looks like a more efficient way.  You can either compare a table (result set) to another table (result set) using the "IN" or "NOT IN" clause.  Or you can compare a scalar (aka variable) to a table (result set) using the "EXISTS" or "NOT EXISTS" clause.

[scalar] EXISTS ([table/result set]) 
[scalar] IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS ([table/result set])

OR

[table/result set] IN ([table/result set])
[table/result set] NOT IN ([table/result set])

```
DECLARE @collection_site_address_id INT;
SET @collection_site_address_id = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        client_address.addressid 
    FROM 
        dbo.ws_test_request
        INNER JOIN client ON ws_test_request.collection_site_id = client.identifyingnumber
        INNER JOIN client_address ON client.clientid = client_address.clientid
    WHERE 
        sample_specimen_id = @sample_identifyingnumber
        AND client_address.addresstypeid = 1
)

IF      
    @collection_site_address_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            [address].addressid
        FROM  
            [address]
            JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    client_address.addressid, 
                    client_address.addresstypeid
                FROM 
                    dbo.fnClientRelatives(@clientid, 0, 1, 0) relatives
                    INNER JOIN client_address on client_address.clientid = relatives.clientid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN client ON relatives.clientid = dbo.client.clientid

                UNION

                SELECT 
                    contact_address.addressid, 
                    contact_address.addresstypeid 
                FROM 
                    clientcontact 
                    INNER JOIN contact_address ON contact_address.contactid=clientcontact.contactid and clientcontact.clientid=@clientid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [contact] ON [clientcontact].contactid = [contact].contactid
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [address] ON contact_address.addressid = address.addressid
            ) AS client_addressexternal ON client_addressexternal.addressid = address.addressid 
        WHERE  
            client_addressexternal.addresstypeid IN (3,1) 
    )
BEGIN
    SET @collection_site_address_id = @default_collection_site_address_id
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra commas in the field list. e.g. replace

```
...
SELECT 
  client_address.addressid,
  client_address.addresstypeid,
FROM
...
```

with

```
...
SELECT 
  client_address.addressid,
  client_address.addresstypeid
FROM
...
```

Comment: and I forgot the SET inside of the BEGIN/END lexical group

Answer (score 1):

You've got trailing commas after the last column in the select lists of those queries. Remove them and that should fix the red lines around the `FROM` keywords, at least.

I.e.:

```
SELECT 
    client_address.addressid, 
    client_address.addresstypeid -- <-- trailing comma removed
FROM [...]

UNION

SELECT 
    contact_address.addressid, 
    contact_address.addresstypeid
FROM [...]
```